# Local Class Import Issues - Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I cannot get Gradle to import classes to its `buildscript`.

Given the following code:

```
import org.vertx.java.platform.impl.cli.Starter

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'

//For build
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath files(dir: './libs', include: '*.jar')  //the files are indeed in the local library folder
    }
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
startup failed:
  build file '/Users/XXX/Projects/Vertx_Server/build.gradle': 1: unable to resolve class org.vertx.java.platform.impl.cli.Starter
   @ line 1, column 1.
     import org.vertx.java.platform.impl.cli.Starter
```

I've used gradle 1.10 and gradle 1.12 with no success (no matter how many combinations of the 'buildscript` or using the 'buildSrc' directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
dependencies {
    classpath fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Comment: i could have sworn i had tried that, but it did the trick. thank you!